# what is the SmartGit equivalent of git reset --hard 9f9f9f9f

Tags: git, smartgit

In SmartGit, I did a check out of an earlier commit, in order to "go back in time". I decided not to provide the name of a branch when prompted for one because it appeared that SmartGit would create a branch and because it seemed unnecessary to create a branch, silly even, if my goal was to simply go back in time on an existing branch. The checkout resulted in a "detached head" so I decided not to continue development on a detached head.

I switched to the command line and did a `git reset --hard 0de799db47f8` using the hash code identified in `git log`. This had the desired effect.

How would I have done this in SmartGit?

Comment: @MartinZeitler your link appears to offer a command line solution. I am seeking a SmartGit solution equivalent to the command line solution.

Comment: see the updated answer ...

Answer (score 1):

in order to accomplish `git reset --hard 0de799db47f8` trough the GUI ...

---

1. in the menu, select `Window` > `Journal`
2. find & right-click commit `0de799db47f8`
3. select `Reset...` from the context menu
4. then choose option `--hard` at the options
5. finally confirm with the `Reset` button

---

[image: SmartGit git reset]

Answer (score 1):

In SmartGit, you can use **Local|Reset** with the **Hard** option to do a `git checkout --hard <SHA>`.